# How to show visio in SharePoint without Visio services

Tags: silverlight

I have a question about presenting a visio file in SharePoint. It doesn't matter in which version (2007 or 2010). Now we have 2007, but they are talking to migrate to 2010 so if you have a solution that only works in 2010, that's fine too.

A bit more info in what I've already tried: As stated in the title, we don't have the visio services available. So I can't use that.
I already exported the visio to a web page (that uses silverlight). This works fine but when you export a visio file to html, it creates an ugly menu on the left that you need to zoom in and change focus (it's called the navigation frame).

So does anyone knows a solution that let's me open my visio on SharePoint with these requirements:
- Needs to be nice, attractive, sexy (it's for customers)
- I need to be able to click on the different objects and they need to link to items on SharePoint.
- I need to be able to click on an object and this would bring me up to another sheet in the visio file.
- Needs to be easy in use and easy maintainable.

So anyone knows a workaround for the navigation pane, a tool to export a visio, ..., ...

I hope my question is clear :-)
Thanks for your help!!

Kind regards,

Jan

Comment: You two are... brilliant! Both solutions work, although both of them have some down sides. The PDF solution is a bit uglier as I'm using more than one sheets. So basically I'm showing a four page pdf where you can scroll to the other pages. The second solution requires visio viewer to be installed by the viewer. The solution is nicer then the pdf solution though... This means I will implement them both and let the management decide which one they like the most :-) Thank you both for your help!!

Comment: btw... How can I set the both answers as answers? I can only select one :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried publishing it as a pdf? Then it works very similarly, all links that you have embedded work the same, the user can download it and keep it as a file on their end or view it in the browser and navigate through it.

Answer (score 0):

I one project (a long long time ago) on 2007 I used Visio Viewer ActiveX control. I don't have code example because we dropped whole project (other reasons) but it worked.

Here you have some links I found:

[Visio 2010: Visio Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21701)

[About Programming Visio Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff768041.aspx)